# Obtaining Density From Homeomorphism onto Image

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function between metric spaces which is a homeomorphism onto its image and let $K\subseteq X$ be non-empty and $D\subseteq Y$ be dense and satisfy
$$
D\cap {f(X)} = f(K).
$$
Then is it the case that $K$ is dense in $X$?

Comment: I mean $D\cap f(X)$.  I made the changes to be clearer, sorry.

Comment: You do know that $D \cap f[X]$ need not be dense in $f[X]$, right?

Comment: I do, but I'm wondering what are necessary and sufficient conditions for it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The assumption that $K$ is nonempty is highly artificial; without it you can simply let $D$ be any dense proper subset of $Y$, let $X=Y\setminus D$ with $f$ the inclusion map, and let $K=\emptyset$.  If you insist on having $K$ nonempty, you can tweak the example by letting $X$ contain a single point of $D$, say.  For instance, you could have $Y=\mathbb{R}$, $D=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, $X=\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\pi\}$, and $K=\{\pi\}$.

Comment: How can I insure that $K\triangleq f^{-1}[D\cap f(X)]$ is dense in $X$ then?

Comment: @N00ber You could demand that $D$ is dense in $f[X]$. And demand $D \subseteq f[K]$.

Comment: Yes, I guess what I'm trying to ask is if $D$ is dense in $Y$ when is its restriction to $f(X)$ guaranteed to be dense if $f(X)$ is non-open (and non-empty).